# Loadrunner, which port does loadrunner use for windows resource monitoring

Tags: loadrunner, perfmon

I need to request firewall access for windows resource monitoring (perfmon).

I know I'll be asked which port loadrunner will connect on. 
I think its port 139, but I can't find where it says it in the help files, can someone confirm ??

Answer (score 0):

It is the same port what PerfMon uses.